# MobaXterm : How to import session database of PuttyCM

Tags: putty, mobaxterm

I am currently using **PuttyCM**  based on Putty to store sessions , urls and keys .

I'm ow switching to **MobaXterm** , and i want to import my database session to my MobaXterm menu .

Is there any way to handle it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible by using **import PuttyCm session** (activated MobaXterm)

Answer (score 1):

For the non-activated version, take a look at this link about Exporting Putty Session info - I'm going to attempt to change the output format to something that MobaXterm would be able to import.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list